# How to get editable changed value from edittext customized list view and stored in array in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am fetching the itemnames from database and append to the edittext (only one editext contains more itemnames) in customized listview. Now I changed values in edittext. How to get all values what I changed in editext.

For example, x,y,z... itemnames comes from database I append with edittext in customized listview now I am changed x,y,z. To a,b,c. Now I want a,b,c(new values) in string array

```
      my code
     View vi = convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);

    EditText text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
    text.append(itemnames[position]);//here i append so many itemnames append to edittext
```

How can I get changed edittext  Values in what are the values are changed means it print all vaules. I try after changed method it print only one name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onTextChanged()` which informs you about changes in EditText.

```
This method is called to notify you that, within *s*, the *count* characters 
beginning at *start* have just replaced old text that had length *before*.
```

---

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: ok .i use above method it can print only one one changed value of edittext. i want print how many values i changed editext it print all

Comment: @Vinoth you mean count of changed values??

Comment: afterchanged text i want store some array . how can store all changed values into array. i print array out side means it prints what i am changed values in editext.. please tell how can i do that

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you are asking. If you want to store changes in a dynamic structure, you should use a `Vector` or `ArrayList` instead of String array.